# How to implement folds and foldsM from pipes-group for the streaming package?

Tags: haskell, streaming

The [pipes-group](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group-1.0.7) library lets you delimit groups in effectful streams without having to hold an entire group in memory at any time.

Two useful function from pipes-groups are [`folds`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group-1.0.7/docs/Pipes-Group.html#v:folds) and [`foldsM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group-1.0.7/docs/Pipes-Group.html#v:foldsM):

> folds :: Monad m  => (x -> a -> x) -> x   -> (x -> b) -> FreeT (Producer
>   a m) m r   -> Producer b m r
>
> foldsM :: Monad m => (x -> a -> m x) -> m x   -> (x -> m b) -> FreeT
>   (Producer a m) m r -> Producer b m r

They summarize each group within a delimited stream and return a stream of the results.

The [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.5) package [also supports delimited streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.5/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#g:5), by using the `Stream` type itself as the functor parameter:

> Stream (Stream (Of a) m) m r

There doesn't seem to exist direct analogues of `folds` and `foldsM` though.
 (Folds for undivided streams [do exist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.5/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#g:7)).

How to implement these functions with the machinery of *streaming*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Streaming.mapped` is the key tool.

```
mapped :: (Monad m, Functor f)
       => (forall x. f x -> m (g x)) 
       -> Stream f m r
       -> Stream g m r

mapped :: (Monad m, Functor f)
       => (forall x. Stream f m x -> m (g x))
       -> Stream (Stream f m) m r
       -> Stream g m r

mapped :: Monad m
       => (forall x. Stream (Of a) m x -> m (Of b x))
       -> Stream (Stream (Of a) m) m r
       -> Stream (Of b) m r
```

We also have the relevant provided folds,

```
fold :: Monad m
     => (x -> a -> x) -> x -> (x -> b)
     -> Stream (Of a) m r -> m (Of b r)

foldM :: Monad m
      => (x -> a -> m x) -> m x -> (x -> m b)
      -> Stream (Of a) m r -> m (Of b r)
```

So you should be able to apply `mapped` to a partially applied `fold` or `foldM` to produce a stream of summaries.

Caution: I have not yet attempted this.